# Is it possible to mount several storage devices at the same location?

Tags: linux, mount, disk, storage

I want to set up several storage device (disk drive, mounted cloud storage) at the same location on a disk to set up a kind of virtual storage made up of several disks for a machine.

The aim is to use them as a large storage unit in which files are in the same folder.

The user will see every file as part of its system, without knowing where the file are actually stored. I would like to have one folder containing every data of every drive without one subdirectory for each mounted unit.

Is it possible?

Comment: In the same directory?

Comment: How should they behave? As a single large volume? Or maybe each drive in its own subdirectory? Should we assume that "dd" means "disk drives" or something else? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: Yes the idea is to have every files/folder of every dd in the same location so the user can access them without knowing where they truly are

Comment: you might be interested in RAID 0 or Linear RAID using mdadm. You'll have to reformat the disks though and be aware that you could lose all the data if one disk dies.

Comment: If we're talking about something that can be accessed at the disk block level (e.g. iSCSI or FibreChannel LUNs, or local disks) then you could use LVM or RAID 0 or RAID 5 to make a single big storage out of multiple disk devices. But if you include mounted cloud storage or anything like NFS that can only be accessed at the filesystem level, that changes things a lot: you would need something like `unionfs` but with multiple writeable devices. You *could* create a disk image file on each storage and run LVM or softRAID on top of them, but that would be an awful kludge - not recommended.

Comment: When reading files, all the files from all the devices are visible. Ok. But what happens when writing a file? Should it be replicated on all the devices? Or should it be written to one specific device? Or something else?

Comment: Thanks for your answer they should be written to one specific device

Comment: "they should be written to one specific device": which one? I mean: how should one underlying device be chosen for a newly created file to be written to?

Answer (score -1):

I've some dev servers where I setup a network mount on a directory with sshfs. It works for programming easy, but depends on the transfers you have to do. With a lot of files sshfs is slow.

Easy command example:

```
sshfs server_host@10.1.1.1:/ map/server_dir
sshfs server_host@10.1.1.2:/var/www/test map/test_dir
```

Comment: Only one of the remote trees is visible at any one time, so this does not do what is requested.